# JSF button onclick event call bean method

Tags: jsf

In the JSF 2, I need to get ready the data before showing a dialog. In the code below, the method 'newAuto' defined in the viewscoped managed bean. once button is clicked, I want to call this method first, then show dialog.

I tried lots of ways, all failed.

thanks

```
<h:commandButton  type="button" value="Add Dialog"   onclick="jsf.ajax.request(this, event, {execute: 'newAuto'});  autoDialog2.show(); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the `<f:ajax>` tag and then its `onevent` attribute.

```
<h:commandButton value="Add Dialog" action="#{bean.newAuto}">
    <f:ajax onevent="function(data) { if (data.status == 'success') autoDialog2.show(); }" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Maybe you also want to add `render="someDialogId"` to `<f:ajax>` which should update the dialog's content beforehand.