# function in my view jsf

Tags: jsf

I debutante in jsf and I wanted to show in a textbox the reference of the client must display and augmeneter implicitly.

Here is the code I've done

```
private int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public void increment() {
        number++;
    }
```

et voici my view :

```
 <h:outputLabel value="N Ticket : "
                    style="font-size:15px; font-family:verdana;" />
                <p:inputText value="#{ticketBean.increment}" />
```

this code it not  works, I wanted to know how I can call my function in my view

Comment: The code is unclear. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign 'void' as value. If you want to increment on clicking a button, then check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065650/jsf-button-onclick-event-call-bean-method)

Comment: thank you for that answer, but I want id ticket appear in a label once the interface appear